# java - file.createNewFile() IOException "No such file or directory"

Tags: java, ioexception

While coding Java had this problem: file.createNewFile() throws IOException "No such file or directory". Checked out other answers but nothing seems to be helpful. Any ideas?..

Comment: ....example code where this error occurs and stack trace is needed to properly answer this question

Comment: Your file path may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I got it. It appeared to be more Windows problem than Java. Actually, even with UAC disabled random app still have no rights to write something on C: (or whatever it is on your system) on Win8. Never got this problem using Win7 though. Using "Run as Administrator" on IDE does not help as it doesn't give such rights to Java compiler. So, I just moved my projects folder to other disk. Also, you can change access rights, but it was easier for me. And yes, nobody mentioned about a chance of this happening in other questions, so I hope it'll be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 13):

It's likely that you're trying to create the file in a directory that does not exist.

Use `mkdirs()` to create any missing parent directories first.

```
File file = new File("foo/bar.txt")
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: I had the same issue as OP and the mkdirs() function was the missing component into fixing the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to create a new file in a directory that does not exist. The whole path needs to exist, only the file can be non-existent.

Comment: Of course it does exsist, I'm not that stupid =) I realized what the problem was and posted answer bellow. Thanks for help =)

Comment: Flag your own answer as recommended then :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the Folder first. createNewFile cannot create them:

```
File folderFile = new File("c:\\this\\folder\\has\\subfolders");
folderFile.mkdirs();

File myFile = new File(folderFile,"myfile.txt");
myFile.createNewFile();
```